# how to retreive image in html img tag in modal using php

Tags: php, modal-dialog

i want to retreive the image from database to display in img tag under modal form using php
Here is my code

```
///prepared statement code for the same
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<img width="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($p_picture).'"/>'; 
}
```

in other webpage forms it is displaying but not in case of modal

Comment: Where is `$p_picture` coming from?

Comment: from bind result

Comment: OK, and have you checked that it actually contains the image? Because I think the only reason why an image doesn't display, given your code, is that there was no image data. Modal or not, that's not relevant.

Comment: In other words: Have you used the browser's web developer tools to inspect the output of your code?

Comment: yes but i have a doubt in my database i have uploaded 400kb image in image column of type blob but when it is saving it is converted into 22kb?can you tell me why it is happening? and you are right the image doesnot show because the image is compressed as stated earlier

Comment: That's a completely different question, best to be asked in a separate question (after you've tried to find an answer yourself), but if your image data is corrupted then it is understandable that the image cannot be displayed.